# SVN Error " Repository moved temporarily to ... please relocate"

Tags: eclipse, apache, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

I have the following error when trying to commit/update/checkout/ a source file/repository or share a new project to a repository from subversive in Eclipse (  Subversive SVN Connector Version    3.0.5.I20140122-1700 id : org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.feature.group Polarion Software, SVNKit implementation version is 1.3.8 )  :

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.

    svn: Commit failed (details follow):
    svn: Repository moved temporarily to '/svn/myproject/trunk/myproject/src/ma/xyz/dao'; please relocate
    svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/myproject/trunk/myproject/src/ma/xyz/dao'
```

I use dav_svn module to access my SVN repository, and Here is what my *httpd.conf* looks like :

```
<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
  SVNPath C:\SVN\repository
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "svn repos"
  AuthUserFile "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\passwd" 
  Require valid-user

</Location>
```

and I have tried to checkout from tortoisesvn client and it's working.

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: for the one who downvoted the question, can I know why ?

Comment: What is version of subversive? Can you add VM arugments `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` and try again?

Comment: @beckyang see my edit

Comment: > SVNKit implementation version is 1.3.8 < is very-very outdated. You should test with up-to-date `svn.exe` client. BTW, you should specify the configuration and the error exactly as you see it. Paths and the other values you removed are essential for investigating this. I personally bet that your server config is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this command. Command description relocate   make sure you run this command on the root of your svn repo folder otherwise it will break.

`svn switch --relocate svn://192.168.0.57/svnrepos svn://192.168.0.32/svnrepos/`

Comment: This post does not answer the question and is wrong. Moreover `svn switch --relocate` is deprecated. Use `svn relocate` instead.